# XSLT match elements with text nodes that do not match the same text node from another element

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

In this sample XML I want to match `app` elements where the text in the `indexInfo` element does not match the same text from the `z_app` element with the same name.

Since the `indexInfo` element from `appname2` and `z_appname2` both match then I don't want to include these.  In this case I would only want app elements `appname1` and `z_appname1` returned since their `indexInfo` content is different.

I'm looking for a match expression that I can use for an XSLT template.

```html
<root>
    <app name="appname1">
      <indexInfo>
This is the text for the indexes
      </indexInfo>
    </app>
    
    <app name="z_appname1">
      <indexInfo>
This is the text for the indexes
But slightly different
      </indexInfo>
    </app>
    
    <app name="appname2">
      <indexInfo>
This is the text for the indexes
      </indexInfo>
    </app>
    
    <app name="z_appname2">
      <indexInfo>
This is the text for the indexes
      </indexInfo>
    </app>
</root>
```

Desired output:

```html
<root>
    <app name="appname1">
      <indexInfo>
This is the text for the indexes
      </indexInfo>
    </app>

    <app name="z_appname1">
      <indexInfo>
This is the text for the indexes
But slightly different
      </indexInfo>
    </app>
</root>
```

Comment: A little further detail -- the rules for this XML is that for every app name there will always be a corresponding z_app name

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="app-by-name" match="app" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="app[starts-with(@name, 'z_')]">
            <xsl:variable name="peer" select="key('app-by-name', substring-after(@name, 'z_'))" />
            <xsl:if test="indexInfo != $peer/indexInfo">
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | $peer"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Both this solution and Mads' solution work however I believe the logic of what I am trying to achieve is easier to follow for this one.  Also the 'indexInfo' element could contain a very large amount of text and may be unwieldy for use as a key.  Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`xsl:key`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#xsl-key) to create a map matching all of the `app` elements, using the value of `@name` after "appname" and the value of the `indexInfo` as the lookup key.

Then, in a template match expression, apply a predicate to match any `app` in which selecting items by that key has more than one item, use an empty template to exclude that matching `app` from the output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:key name="app" match="app" use="concat(substring-after(@name, 'appname'), '|', indexInfo)"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="app[key('app', concat(substring-after(@name, 'appname'), '|', indexInfo))[2]]"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Mads - see my response to Michael's below.  Yours does work also but see my reasons below for not picking this one.